# dynamically adding a new Table object in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**I will try create a new Table object using an object,but the problem am facing is while add a new row(new table object) it shows a number of columns of previous object, I need new table object with single row, if i need column to particular row it should add column to that row only**

```js
.TS

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 
r1=1;

oldJson = [
  {
    key1: this.r1
  }
]

newJson= [
  {
    key2: this.oldJson
  }
]


 new1(){
  try{ 
        this.r1 = this.r1 + 1;
        this.oldJson.push({
          key1: this.r1
        });
      } catch(error){ console.log(error)}
      }


      new2() {
        this.newJson.push({
      key2: this.oldJson
        });
      }
}
```

```css
.css

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
.html

<table *ngFor="let item of newJson"  >
      <tr>                   
           <td *ngFor="let x of item.key2" >
        </td>
        <button class="add" (click)="new1(i)">addcolumn</button>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
<button class="add" (click)="new2(i)">addrow</button>
```

In this snippet typescript functions not working but it works in vs code, so please consider only the code.
thanks in advance

Comment: Use **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfvrox)** for Typescript & Angular code snippets.

Comment: your `json` structure is wrong

Comment: Its not an exact json just am putting variable name thats it

Comment: how to write it in a proper way will you help me

Answer (score 0):

**The template:**

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      <input [(ngModel)]="row[col]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button (click)="addColumn()">Add Column</button>
<button (click)="addRow()">Add Row</button>

<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

**The code:**

```
  data = [{ col1: 'one', col2: 'two' }, { col1: 'uno', col2: 'duo' }];
  emptyObject = { col1: 'ww', col2: 'gg' };
  index = 3;
  columns = ['col1', 'col2'];

  addRow() {
    this.data.push(Object.assign({}, this.emptyObject));
  }
  addColumn() {
    const c = 'col' + this.index++;
    this.columns.push(c);
    this.emptyObject[c] = 'edit me';
    this.data.forEach(row => row[c] = 'edit me');
  }
```

Comment: new2() {
       
        this.newJson.push({
      key2: this.oldJson = [
        {
          key1: this.r1=1
        }
      ]
        });
      }                                                                                                                             its working to me but once i insert an row only in that row i can able to add the columns, but i need it in every row whenever i want to add a new column

Comment: You should separate structure from data. use a columns array. eg.:                    
           <td *ngFor="let x of columns" > {{item[x]}}</td>

Comment: I didn't get it , because what i know in angular is <td *ngFor="let x of columns"> {{x.key}}// then it gives me key value

Comment: item.key2[x]. Or you have to use a script to add the new column for every row. A little bit confusing a json structure for me.

Comment: forget about my json structure, actually what i need is i have to create one table with n number of rows and columns dynamically, will you help me for that

Comment: Something like this : <tr *ngFor="let row of data"><td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{row[col]}}</td></tr> addRow(){this.data.push(this.emptyObject)}  emptyObject={col1:'', col2:''} index=2; columns:['col1', 'col2']; addColumn(){const c = 'col' + this.index++; this.columns.push(c); this.emptyObject[c] = '';}

Comment: this.data means shall i declare a variable, because it show me an error in data and rows

Comment: data contain the rows of the table. You can set it or fetch it from server. It has a lightweight structure, a simple array of objects.

Comment: if you don't mind are you able execute this code in angular 4, because i will try it many times but it didn't works to me

Comment: works for me. I've replaced with the corrected version.